# Algorithm to find discriminating data points?

Tags: algorithm

Given n samples and p >> n (discrete) data points for each of the n samples, what is a good algorithm for finding a smallest possible set of k data points such that those k data points discriminate between all n samples?

For my purposes, a good algorithm that finds an approximately smallest set would also suffice.

Comment: just to verify, that I understand this correctly, k>=log(n), right?

Comment: Also to clarify, when you say "discriminate between all n samples," I assume that you're looking for a set of indices such that for each index, all the data points at that index have different values?  Or do you mean that given just the k columns from the data points, no two samples will appear the same?  The former is a much stronger condition than the latter, so I'd like to make sure I'm thinking about the right problem. :-)

Comment: I thought there are no "columns", it's just a *set* of data points

Comment: I'm just doing some tests.. what is the range of n and p, and how diverse are data points?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds as though your problem is closely related to the test cover problem. The test cover problem is, given a ground set X = {1, …, n} and a collection T = {T<sub>1</sub>, …, T<sub>m</sub>} of subsets of X, to find the smallest subcollection U of T such that for all y ≠ z in X, there exists a set S in T such that either (x in S and y not in S) or (x not in S and y in S).

The test cover problem is NP-hard, so in practice, optimal solutions are found using branch and bound techniques. See [De Bontridder et al.](http://jorlin.scripts.mit.edu/docs/publications/119-testSetCover.pdf)

Comment: How can you transform one problem to the other?

Comment: @yi_H If the data points are binary, then let Ti consist of the samples with 1 for the ith data point.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple greedy algorithm, shouldn't generate too bad results:

Check if data points are same for two different elements, if so, there is no solution.

- In each step we add one new data point to the set `k`.
- We test all the different points in all of the `p` in `n`.

  - Try to add that point to `k`.
  - The new `k` divides `n` into a couple of distinct sets (some of these
    contain just one element, some more.. finally all will contain just one).
  - Pick the point which generates
    the most sets.
- Do this till all sets are distinct.